# Remove last Character of every Item in the list

Tags: vb.net

I have a list `Owner.PluginXML.Blacklist` that is filled manually with FilePaths `directory.FullName`. The List is later being used as a blacklist with the `.Contains` Method.

```
If Owner.PluginXML.DeleteBlacklist.Contains(directory.FullName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    Return
End If
```

`.Contains` doesn't work if the FilePaths end with a `\`. I would use `.EndsWith` to check if there even is a `\`, but I'm struggling with how to remove the last character of every Item. How would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
With Owner.PluginXML.DeleteBlacklist
    For i = 0 To .Count - 1
        .Item(i) = .Item(i).TrimEnd("\"c)
    Next
End With
```